React Native Modal Styling Errors
I'm trying to create a Modal component in React Native, but my styling is not working as intended. I have two problems:

My Modal does not stretch the width of the screen. It only seems to be as long as the components inside the Modal.
I want to add a small border radius to the Modal, but it isn't being applying.


Below is the code inside the Modal component:
<Modal {...props} animationType={'fade'} transparent={true}>
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', flex:1}}>
        <View 
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                borderRadius: theme.popup.borderRadius,
                padding: theme.popup.padding
            }}>
            <View 
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: theme.colors.background,
                    flex: theme.popup.flexBody
                }}>
                {children}
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={togglePopup}
                style={{
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
                    flex: theme.popup.flexClose,
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                <Ionicons name={'close-circle-outline'} size={40} color={theme.colors.secondary}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
</Modal>

I have also provided the necessary values for theme.popup:
popup: {
    borderRadius: 30,
    padding: 10, // Tailwind px-6 equivalent in pixels
    flexBody: 4, // Body takes up 4/5ths of popup height
    flexClose: 1 // Close button takes up 1/5th of popup height
}

Please help me solve this. Thank you!
-NCI

Try width: '100%', in the first View after Modal component

Yeah, I ended up fixing it by adding margins. I misunderstood how CSS works and it's looking much better now. Thanks for the response tho :)
